# Events and the DriveInfo class

Tags: c#, events, driveinfo

I have a class that has a property of type DriveInfo, which has a boolean property of IsReady as you might already know. This is a value representing when the drive is "ready" - for me, that means that there's a CD in the drive, as I've chosen only CDRom drives.

What I would like to do is call an event when the property is updated - currently I'm instantiating the object, then performing a while loop to wait for the value to be true.

```
    public bool WaitUntilReady()
    {
        while (!Cancelled)
        {
            if (Drive.IsReady) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I'd much prefer a method, or something similar. Thank you.

Comment: This is bogus code. You are in a while loop and every call causes a recursive call to `WaitUntilReady` again. Don't do that!

Comment: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged or another event in the `Drive` class that gets raised when the value changes. Or do you have to poll the hardware?

Comment: @mvondano I don't know what that means - could you show me some examples? People have told me about INotifyPropertyChanged, but I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Ah I just realized you meant the System.IO.Drive class - if so forget about my comment. INotifyPropertyChanged is just an interface that forces you to implement an event, that notifies about changing values. So perhaps you should read something about how events work. (But actually that is not what ought to be your problem here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're waiting for changes in device state such as CD insertion/ removal, listening to [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message would be a better way.

> Windows sends all top-level windows a set of default `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages when new devices or media (such as a CD or DVD) are added and become available, and when existing devices or media are removed... [Read More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Try using the following helper class to listen for media insertion/ removal:

**DriveHelper**

```
public static class DriveHelper
{
  const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
  const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
  const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004;
  const int DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME = 0x00000002;
  const ushort DBTF_MEDIA = 0x0001;

  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  struct DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
  {
    public uint dbch_Size;
    public uint dbch_Devicetype;
    public uint dbch_Reserved;
    public uint dbch_Unitmask;
    public ushort dbch_Flags;
  }

  public class StateChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
  {
    public StateChangedEventArgs(string drive, bool ready)
    {
      Drive = drive;
      Ready = ready;
    }

    public string Drive { get; private set; }

    public bool Ready { get; private set; }
  }

  public static void QueryDeviceChange(Message m, Action<StateChangedEventArgs> action)
  {
    if (action == null || m.Msg != WM_DEVICECHANGE) return;

    var devType = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);
    if (devType != DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME) return;

    var lpdbv = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));
    if (lpdbv.dbch_Flags != DBTF_MEDIA) return;

    var eventCode = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    var drive = GetFirstDriveFromMask(lpdbv.dbch_Unitmask);

    switch (eventCode)
    {
      case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
        action(new StateChangedEventArgs(drive, true));
        break;
      case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
        action(new StateChangedEventArgs(drive, false));
        break;
    }
  }

  static string GetFirstDriveFromMask(uint mask)
  {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
      if ((mask & 0x1) == 0x1)
        break;
      mask = mask >> 1;
    }

    return string.Concat((char)(i + 65), @":\");
  }
}
```

**Usage Example** *(for `Windows Forms` apps)*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();      
  }

  void OnStateChanged(DriveHelper.StateChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    // do your work here
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Drive: {0} => e.Ready: {1}, DriveInfo.IsReady: {2}", e.Drive, e.Ready, new DriveInfo(e.Drive).IsReady));
  }    

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
    DriveHelper.QueryDeviceChange(m, OnStateChanged);

    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }      
}
```

Comment: I didn't really understand WMI before this post, and the code example is spoonfed so thank you very much for this, I appreciate it. I'm still wrapping my head around events :(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be informed when a CD/DVD is inserted. So this maybe could help: [Detect CD-ROM Insertion](http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/Detect_CD-ROM_Insertion)

I think this solves your problem with WMI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do make a call that happens every x timeunins you could do something like this with the help of tasks and async/await:

```
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cts.Token;

    Task yourTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {               
            // run in a loop until aborted
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            // do your request here ...

            // wait
            await Task.Delay(theTimeIntervalToWait, token);
        }
    }, token);
```

Then you can use `cts.Cancel();` to abort your task (from outside). If you want to make sure it has completed you might then call `yourTask.Wait()`.

Generally speaking you should in most cases not use something like `while(true) { permanently-polling }`.